# Slim framework select 30 random rows from 500K rows fast

Tags: php, sql

I am new in slim framework i use this php code to get random items

```
function getItems()
    {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    try {
        $items = \ORM::for_table('item')->order_by_expr('rand()')->limit(30)->find_array();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        $app->firephp->error($e);
        $items = array();
        }

    return array(
        'Items' => $items
    );
    }
```

but this is slow how i can get fast result?

thank you.

Comment: Not related to Slim. More related to ORM you are using.

Comment: Not related to the ORM, more related to the false notion that you can get a fast query result from ordering results randomly with a `LIMIT` of 30 (or any number for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

When you use `ORDER BY RAND()` you are *loading and then ordering the entire result set by the randomization function*, and **then** limiting the result to 30. Your query is fundamentally inefficient.

You'd have a better time fetch all of the IDs from the table, using [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on the resulting array set, and then using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the first 30 IDs of the randomized result. Or you can use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) thirty times over in a loop to build your selection array. This can then be utilized in some sort of `WHERE IN` clause.

Another option is a sub-query by selecting just IDs sorted randomly with a limit in the sub-query.

Comment: Thank you can write sample code with shuffle and array_slice?